# Secure ClickOnce files so that only my users can access it?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, clickonce, wpftoolkit, lan

I am trying to deploy my WPF application to some users who are outside of our corporate network. Everything works great on our LAN but I can't get the updates working when I turn on security as the user is never prompted for their login details?

Does anyone know of a way to secure my ClickOnce files so that only my users can access it? I am not allowed to put this software up without it being secure.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to secure your files as the ClickOnce runtime will blindly return to it's deployment point and never keep hold of the users original credentials. I have heard of ways of getting round this using various techniques but its a fair bit of work.

This might be of use [www.clickoncerevolution.com](http://www.clickoncerevolution.com).

You could also always consider an MSI installer but you won't get the automatic updates.

Marty

Answer (score 0):

Internally, you can restrict access to the files on the webserver. Externally, there's not much you can do easily.

We handle this by having our customers log in when they run the application, and we verify their credentials against backend services (running on Azure). So they can't run it unless they can log in.

If you don't want to do that, I'll share [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff699325.aspx) with you. It shows how to serve up your ClickOnce files from a SQL Server database by intercepting the requests to the webserver and responding. If you were smarter with web applications than I am (not a high bar, mind you), maybe you could figure out how to intercept and ask for authentication credentials at that point.

And here's [an article from CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-security/ClickOnceFormsAuth.aspx?display=Print) where they show one solution for what you're trying to do.